# jQuery countTo plugin - Want to have new instance of countTo on every data attribute change

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am trying to provide preview of numbers to the user, so when the user inputs data-to,data-from and data-speed values (through input fields), the data values are updated in the span below -

```
<span 
  id="demo-shuffling-numbers" 
  class="shuffling-numbers" 
  data-from="" 
  data-to="" 
  data-speed=""
></span>
```

For preview the user needs to click the preview button.

I am facing a problem where only the values entered the first time are used by the countTo plugin and not the consecutive changes.

The data attributes gets changed when the input values are changed but the preview appears with first inputed values only (no effect after new values are submitted).

I am using the below jQuery for updating and triggering countTo plugin -

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#shuffling-numbers-preview').click(function(){
    $('#demo-shuffling-numbers').countTo();
  });

  $('#shuffling_numbers-start_from').change(function() {
    $('#shuffling_numbers-start_from').each(function(index) {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $('#demo-shuffling-numbers').attr('data-from',value );
      $('#demo-shuffling-numbers').html(value);
    });

  });

  $("#shuffling_numbers-end_to").change(function() {
    $("#shuffling_numbers-end_to").each(function(index) {
      $("#demo-shuffling-numbers").attr("data-to", $(this).val());
    });

  });
});
```

How can I make the countTo plugin count up or down to the new values?

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Got a workaround by removing and inserting span on every button click. If there is any better workaround then do let me know. Thanks!